# buggy recursive printtree function in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

```
#------start code---------------------------------
#   in: $a0, the parent node that 
#---------------------------------------
printtree:


    subu $sp,$sp,8
    sw  $ra,4($sp)  #save ra
    sw  $a0,8($sp)  #push node
    lw  $a0,12($sp) #access argument node to $a0
    j   ptexit

ptloop:
    subu $sp,$sp,4  
    lw  $a0,4($a0)
    sw  $a0,4($sp)  #push [esi+4]
    jal printtree   #call printtree2    
    add $sp,$sp,8

    lw  $a1,0($a0)  #at this point $a0 holds a node 
    lw  $a1,0($a1)
    jal printInteger    #this function just prints value of $a1
    lw  $a0,12($a0)

ptexit:

    bnez    $a0,ptloop      #jump ptloop if $a0 ne to zero

    lw  $ra,4($sp)
    lw  $a0,8($sp)      #get the returned values from the stack back to $a0
    add $sp,$sp,8
    jr  $r              #go to $ra
#----------end code--------
```

the above code is supposed to print a binary tree from smallest to highest
given the top node,somewhere,somehow something is ruining the stack,causing exception.thank you very much

Comment: Your stack operations look a bit unorthodox. A "push" operation typically pre-decrements the stack pointer and then writes to the top of the stack, and "pop operations typically read from the top of the stack and then post-increments the stack pointer. For example, to push a 32-bit register one would first decrement `$sp` by 4 and then store the register at `0($sp)`.

Comment: Another thing that struck me as odd is that you seem to use the stack for argument passing, which is not how one usually would do it on MIPS. The first four integer arguments are passed in registers `$a0..$a3`.

Comment: it became that way because my ways of doing the stack came from using the x86 arch. and ive used to the convention of using the stack to access the parameters of a function.and debugging in mips using qtspim is really laborious. do you know a much more softice or ollydbg like debugger for it?

Answer (score 0):

got it fixed recently, and as far as i tested it works fine.to use it, pass a parent node to 0($sp)like the code below:

```
sub $sp,$sp,4
sw  $v1,0($sp)
jal printtree
add $sp,$sp,4
```

## ----------------------------------------------------

```
 printtree:

    sub $sp,$sp,8
    sw  $a0,0($sp)  #save orig $a0 as new TOS
    sw  $ra,4($sp)  #save return address as TOS+4
    lw  $a0,8($sp)  #access param1 in TOS+8

    j   leftmost

recur:
    sub $sp,$sp,4   
    lw  $a1,4($a0)  #access node->left
    sw  $a1,0($sp)  #push it to the stack
    jal printtree


    lw  $a1,0($a0)  # $a1 should contain node->data
    jal printInteger    # calls a syscall function that prints $a1 value to console

    #node is assumed to be in $a0
    lw  $a0,8($a0)  #access node->right

leftmost:
    bne $a0,$zero,recur
    lw  $a0,0($sp)  #hold the previous node
    lw  $ra,4($sp)  #hold the return address
    add $sp,$sp,12
    jr  $ra
```

## ----------------------------------------------------